# Submit a portion of a form's controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net

There's probably a super-simple answer to this, but my head is spinning...

I have an ASP.Net webforms page that contains a large table.  Many of the form elements within this table are for client-side calculation of values, that are used to populate other elements.  The problem is that the post collection is very large because of the unecessary data that is posted.

The elements in Column 2, below, populate the value of the input field in Column 3:

[image]

When the form is submitted, the code only requires values from the two hidden fields, and the result field.

The problem is that for some users, this table is very large, resulting in very large POST to the server.  Within this post, all the *Calculation* fields are also submitted, which further adds to the size of the post collection.

ASP.Net's ViewState has been disabled, which worked well.  However, there is still large amounts of data being posted, which is unneccessary.

My questions therefore are:

1. In ASP.Net MVC is it possible to circumvent this issue, or does the whole form still get posted by the very nature of a `<form>`'s behaviour?
2. If I use JQuery to iterate the table and submit the necessary values only to an API endpoint instead, does that present any security risks that didn't exist before
3. Is there a better approach altogether?

Comment: remove the names from the calculation fields

Comment: Nice idea - I didn't even know that this had the desired effect.  The only problem is that ASP.Net needs to names to retrieve the data.

Comment: ? You name the fields you want to send. You omit the names (use ID or class or whatever) from the fields you do not want to send.

Comment: Okay yes.  I'd have to use MVC for that as webforms creates the name values as part of its rendering routine.  Thanks

Comment: Then use jQuery to grab the fields you need and ajax them - or remove all names of class="calc" before submitting

Comment: I knocked up a JQuery test (leaving names in for now) that works well, which was the driver for question 2 :-)

Comment: Give all fields you want to send a class and then do `data: $("myFieldsToSend").serialize()` - or use the .not to leave out the class="calc"